# While using debug module does Ansible ssh to the hosts

Tags: ssh, ansible, xdebug, ssh-keys

```yaml
- hosts : all
  tasks:
   - debug: var=inventory_hostname
```

If this playbook is executed on multiple servers, does it work like ping test or does it only give the inventory varible without reaching the server through ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the playbook with the `-vvvvv` flag to get all debug information Ansible can produce.

You will notice that for this particular playbook you prepared, Ansible will connect to the servers to run the "facts gathering" routines (since you omitted it, its assumed that `gather_facts = true`).

If you explicitly set `gather_facts = false` and run again, you will see that in the debug information that Ansible doesn't SSH to the servers.